# SQL trying to group by ID and keep variable based on category

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure how to explain this, but I have a dataset with a ID variable PassengerID, and then a time variable "Time" and a category variable for each transaction each passenger makes "ItemA" or "ItemB"

In this case I have created dummy variables for ItemA and ItemB and both rows will have variable Time

Basically I want to group the Passengers together so I know Passenger 1 bought ItemA at TimeA and ItemB at TimeB.

My first thought was to create TimeA and TimeB variables

```
select (case when ItemA=1 then Time) end as TimevarA,
       (case when ItemB=1 then Time) end as TimevarB
```

Trying to figure out how to

```
group by PassengerID
```

where I can have Time=TimeA for ItemA and Time=TimeB when ItemB

Data would look something like

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
passengerID varchar(100),
itemA VARCHAR(100),
itemB VARCHAR(100),
timevar date
)
insert into @t values
('1','1','0','2015-01-01'),
('1','0','1','2015-02-01')
```

While the goal would be

```
DECLARE @goal TABLE(
passengerID varchar(100),
itemA VARCHAR(100),
itemB VARCHAR(100),
timevarA date,
timevarB date
)
insert into @goal values
('1','1','1','2015-01-01','2015-02-01')
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: This is a *good* question: Sample data, own attempt, expected output... Upvote from my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, if you have your data like

```
('1','1','0','2015-01-01'), ('1','0','1','2015-02-01')
```

You can obtain your "goal" using like the SELECT below

```
SELECT PassengerID,
       max(itemA) itemA,
       max(itemB) itemB,
       max(case when ItemA = 1 then Time end) as timevarA,
       max(case when ItemB = 1 then Time end) as timevarB
FROM @t
GROUP BY PassengerID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for conditional aggregation.

```
select PassengerID,
       max(case when ItemA = 1 then Time end) as TimevarA,
       max(case when ItemB = 1 then Time end) as TimevarB
from @t
group by PassengerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should reshape your data. ie:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
  (
    passengerID VARCHAR(100) ,
    item VARCHAR(100) ,
    timevar DATE
  );
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '1', 'itemA', '2015-01-01' ),
        ( '1', 'itemB', '2015-02-01' );

SELECT  *
FROM    @t data PIVOT ( MAX([timevar]) FOR [item] IN ( [itemA], [itemB] ) ) pvt;
```